# Trigger Business Process and Send E-mail

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

How can I trigger the business process and update order status and send e-mail for an order by manually in backoffice ?

For example change the order status from order confirmed then order completed and send order completation e-mail.

Can you quickly explain ?

I couldn’t find how can I trigger process and update order status

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a action button to backoffice or you can add interceptor for order model and check the status.

Then you can start a business process with `BusinessProcessService.startProcess()`.

OOTB we have order business process (order-process.xml) and it sends some notifications. Generally every project has their own order process, check the implementation.